# exploding <table>, <div> from sql content

Tags: php, mysql, echo, explode

I have a line in my template that I need help fixing.

If a user posts opening `<div>` tags or closing `</div>`, or any other structure related HTML tags into the content, it will result in a template mess on the page.

I'm using `htmlentities` on titles, and other forms. Unfortunately, I can't do that here, because the content field has a rich editor, and I need to keep the text styling tags intact (`<b>`, `<u>`, colors, `<i>` and such).

Right now, it's very easy for users to mess up the template on purpose and I want to prevent that.

Comment: Are you actually asking about your `wordwrap`, or are you just asking how to allow *some* HTML tags and block others? It's not totally clear from your question.

Comment: @John Flatness john im talking about HTML tags, some-how i got everyone mis-understood. the issue right now is not with the  wordwrap

Comment: Is [`Tidy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) available on your server or can you install it?

Comment: no, it's not possible to install it.
i still need help. if anyone know how to do that

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to throw the text into a DOM parser and have it sort out any mess. Such a tool will probably be more robust than anything you can put together, including solving problems you didn't know you might have.

Comment: how do i do that?
John Wheal: it won't work. i tried it. it might work with words but when typing the long same letter without spaces it will not break the line. even with width added.

Comment: This is not a SQL issue.  It's something for your host language to deal with.  See http://htmlparsing.com/php for pointers to PHP HTML parsers.

Comment: @Andy Lester i'm looking at it right now. but still, is there any script i could use to do what i wanted only for the $content variable?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've clarified in the comments what the actual problem is, I may be able to help. The issue is basically that you don't want long words entered by the user to break the page layout.

The PHP `wordwrap` solution you've come up with already has numerous problems, of which the one you've found (breaking your HTML) is the most obvious.

However, since the issue is purely a question of not wanting to allow long words to break your page layout, there are several other solutions that could be used instead.

1. Do something specific to any excessively long words, rather than to the whole text. You could add manual breaks to them, spaces, or the HTML `<wbr>` tag (which is an optional line-break, ie for hyphenation purposes). Or you could even just block users from entering crazy long words in the first place.
2. CSS `overflow-x:hidden`
   Using this, any text overflowing out of the side of the box will simply be hidden, rather than be printed on top of other parts of the page.
3. CSS `word-wrap`
   There are several ways of doing this, and it gets a little tricky because of varying browser support. But here's a link that explains it all: http://blog.kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/

Hope that helps.

Comment: i will follow that, even though i've found another code for word wrap (i'm going to use your suggestion in it). but my main issue right now is not with the wrap, but is with the explode.